Это аналогия или что-то другое?
Приведем пример: Человек говорит мне «Косметика уродует человека», а я отвечаю ему «Картину маслом не испортишь».
Картина в высказывании — лицо человека
Масло в высказывании — косметика
Я привела аналогию или что я сделала? Как называется этот прием?

Метафора и мем. Метафора, потому что вы заменили одни слова совершенно другими, сохранив подобие их взаимодействия, а мем, потому что "кашу маслом не испортишь" и "картина маслом" - совсем иные фразеологизмы, на слуху, которые вы совместили и исказили под свои нужды.

Я бы поправил: картину маслом маслом не испортить.
